# TikZ: Filling a rectangle with dot grid

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to fill the rectangle between two points with dots in a regular way. Sounds like a pattern, but apparently, patterns cause difficulties when it comes to absolute positions. Hence, I tried the following:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
    grid/.style={
        to path={
            coordinate (from)
            ++(1,1) coordinate (step)
            (\tikztotarget) coordinate (to)
            \pgfextra{
                \path (from);
                \pgfgetlastxy{\XFrom}{\YFrom}
                \path (step);
                \pgfgetlastxy{\XStep}{\YStep}
                \path (to);
                \pgfgetlastxy{\XTo}{\YTo}
                \edef\List{\XFrom, \XStep, ...pt, \XTo}
                \show\List
                \foreach \i in \List {
                    \fill[black] (\i, 0pt) circle (0.3pt);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (-1,-1) edge[grid] (5,5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This does not work: Although `\show\List` gives `->-28.45274pt, 0.0pt, ...pt, 142.26372pt.`, the following `\foreach` cannot parse the pattern. Why?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a `grid` and `dash pattern` with `line cap=round`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{mygrid/.style={line width=3pt, dash pattern=on 0mm off 10mm, line cap=round}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[gray!20] (-1.4,-1.5) rectangle (5.3,5.2);
\draw[mygrid] (-1,-1) grid (5,5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `path picture` to achieve this:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
    pseudo pattern/.style={
        fill=yellow,
        path picture={
            \path (path picture bounding box.south west);
            \pgfgetlastxy{\xsw}{\ysw}
            \path (path picture bounding box.north east);
            \pgfgetlastxy{\xne}{\yne}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\w}{\xne / 1cm - \xsw / 1cm + 1}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\h}{\yne / 1cm - \ysw / 1cm + 1}
            \begin{scope}[shift={(path picture bounding box.south west)}]
                \foreach \x in {0, 1, ..., \h} {
                    \foreach \y in {0, 1, ..., \w} { 
                        \fill[red] (\x,\y) circle[radius=1pt];
                    }
                }
            \end{scope}
        }
    }
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill[pseudo pattern] (-1,-1) rectangle (5,5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Note that patterns are positioned absolutely on the page, but their position is not necessarily always at the origin of the `tikzpicture`. Refer to the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \draw[pattern={Dots[distance=1cm]}] (0.5,-1) rectangle (5,5);
    \draw[red, pattern={Dots[distance=1cm]}, pattern color=red] (1,-1) rectangle (5.5,5);
    %\path (-0.25,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can clearly see that the dots of the first and of the second pattern are exactly at the same position although one of the rectangles is shifted by 0.5 cm. If you uncommend the `\path` command, you will see that the dots are shifted to the left, but again, the patterns of both rectangles match. In this way you are right that it is not completely reliable to tell where the origin of the pattern is.

[image]

---

To ensure that one point of the pattern is always at `(0,0)`, my original answer could be amended like following:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength{\pseudopatternstep}
\setlength{\pseudopatternstep}{1cm}
\tikzset{
    pseudo pattern step/.code={\pgfmathsetlength{\pseudopatternstep}{#1}},
    pseudo pattern color/.style={.},
    pseudo pattern/.style={
        fill=none,
        path picture={
            \path (path picture bounding box.south west);
            \pgfgetlastxy{\xsw}{\ysw}
            \path (path picture bounding box.north east);
            \pgfgetlastxy{\xne}{\yne}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\ox}{int(\xsw / \the\pseudopatternstep) * \the\pseudopatternstep / 1cm}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\oy}{int(\ysw / \the\pseudopatternstep) * \the\pseudopatternstep / 1cm}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\sx}{\the\pseudopatternstep / 1cm + \ox}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\sy}{\the\pseudopatternstep / 1cm + \oy}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\w}{\xne / 1cm - \xsw / 1cm + 1}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\h}{\yne / 1cm - \ysw / 1cm + 1}
            \begin{scope}
                \foreach \x in {\ox, \sx, ..., \h} {
                    \foreach \y in {\oy, \sy, ..., \w} { 
                        \fill[pseudo pattern color] (\x,\y) circle[radius=1pt];
                    }
                }
            \end{scope}
        }
    }
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) circle[radius=5pt];
        \fill[draw, pseudo pattern, pseudo pattern color/.style=black!20] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
        \fill[draw=red, pseudo pattern, pseudo pattern color/.style=black!40] (-0.5,-0.5) rectangle (4.5,4.5);
        \fill[draw=blue, pseudo pattern] (-2.25,-2.25) rectangle (2.75,2.75);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[pseudo pattern step=10pt]
        \draw (0,0) circle[radius=5pt];
        \fill[draw, pseudo pattern, pseudo pattern color/.style=black!20] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
        \fill[draw=red, pseudo pattern, pseudo pattern color/.style=black!40] (-0.5,-0.5) rectangle (4.5,4.5);
        \fill[draw=blue, pseudo pattern] (-2.25,-2.25) rectangle (2.75,2.75);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi. That looks great. But how can I make sure that there is always a point on (0,0), no matter what the rectangle is? I'm struggling on bringing the necessary shift into tikz.

Comment: @Bubaya So, you want the lower west coordinate and (0,0) define the grid?

Comment: @Bubaya ... because, if you want the grid to be positioned absolutely, then it would be pretty much a pattern.

Comment: I think your last remark is not true. If I try ```\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
  \fill[pattern={Dots[distance=1cm]}] (-0.6,-1) rectangle (5,5);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}```then I don't see how the positioning of the dots has anything to do with where the origin is. Could you elaborate on your comment?

Comment: The position of patterns is not decided by the bb, -it is not controlled by TikZ or PGF, but at a even lower level - PDF/PS. In fact the phase of patterns is not well-defined. -all that can be know is that the pattern position is fixed all over a page. Edit: I see now that you are not using real patterns. I was too fast - just read the above comment. I do not know about `patterns.meta`

Comment: @hpekristiansen Thank you! You are right. I corrected this in my answer. The reason why I mentioned the positioning of patters in the first place is that I was unsure that the OP was aiming for (because "absolutely positioned" can mean different things). If they only want two shapes with matching patterns, than they could just use a pattern. But obviously this is not exactly what they want. I think my last edit should be about something in the right direction.